# PHP post request

Tags: php, post, curl, httprequest

I have to make a request post using PHP, but I can not make it work. the low html request works

```
<form action="http://example.com/form.php" method="post" id="form-success">
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="itemid" value="12345">
<input type="hidden" name="key" id="sh" value="79c830e5bf78218685a350cd5df3cdac">
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I tried this two ways to request in php but both does not work.

```
$content = http_build_query(array('id'=>'12345','key'=>'79c830e5bf78218685a350cd5df3cdac'));

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $content,
    )
));

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/form.php', null, $context);

echo $result;
```

and

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/form.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('id'=>'12345','key'=>'79c830e5bf78218685a350cd5df3cdac');

$pagina = curl_exec ($ch);

echo $pagina;
```

has no error message, just know that the page is not redirected correctly.
any ideas?
thank you

Comment: Could be the server blocks some user agents (or no user agent string). Try adding a user agent string to the curl http://davidwalsh.name/set-user-agent-php-curl-spoof

Comment: When you submit the form, you will get redirected to form.php with your data in $_POST. What exactly, is not working? What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: alter user agent not work!

Comment: I have to submit the form to the page from a client, this page must process the two variables and redirect to another page, when she did not processesa corretamete for some reason it does not redirect the page.

Comment: Beauty worked with user agent "Mozilla / 5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit / 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / Safari 39.0.2171.71 / 537.36" thank you @logic-unit

Answer (score 0):

I use this :

```
function file_get_contents_post($url, $var_post = array()) {
    define('MULTIPART_BOUNDARY', '--------------------------'.microtime(true));
    $header = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='.MULTIPART_BOUNDARY;
    $content = '' ;

    foreach ( $var_post as $key => $value ) {
        $content .= "--".MULTIPART_BOUNDARY."\r\n".
                    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"".$key."\"\r\n\r\n".
                    $value."\r\n";
    }

    $content .= "--".MULTIPART_BOUNDARY."--\r\n";

    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'header' => $header,
              'content' => $content,
        )
    ));
    return file_get_contents($url, false, $context) ;
}
```